# Runtime error on Ideone Java Program

Tags: java, object, split, runtime

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */

class time
{
    int h,m,sec;
    void getdata()throws IOException
    { /*Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);`
      h=in.nextInt();
      m= in.nextInt();
      s=in.nextInt();*/
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String s= br.readLine();
        String str[] = s.split(" ");

        h=Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
        m=Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
        sec=Integer.parseInt(str[2]);
    }
    int calc_time(time t1,time t2)
    { return ((t2.h - t1.h)*3600 + (t2.m - t1.m)*60 + (t2.sec - t1.sec));
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        time t = new time();
        t.getdata();
        time te = new time();
        te.getdata();
        time tt = new time();
        int val = tt.calc_time(t,te);
        if(val>=0&&val<=99) System.out.println("S");
        else if(val>99&&val<=199) System.out.println("C");
        else if(val>199 && val<=299) System.out.println("S");
        else if(val>299 && val<=399) System.out.println("C");

    }
}
```

I'm getting a Runtime error for this particular program on Ideone although it's working perfectly on my PC.
It indicates error for the split function and the getdata() function call by the second object.

Comment: and the error message is ?

Comment: Which RunTimeException you got?

Comment: http://ideone.com/qpOO9R

Comment: You mean there is a bug in IDEONE ?

Answer (score 1):

http://ideone.com/qpOO9R

Your end of stream to STDIN has been reached, meaning that after the following is run:

```
  String s = br.readLine();
```

`s` is still null, which causes a NPE on the following line:

```
String str[] = s.split(" ");
```

To fix this, check for a null and do something reasonable, and provide some input for Ideone to work with. Additionally, your BufferedReader should only be created once per execution, as shown in this ideone sketch: http://ideone.com/VtQrxk

Relevant javadoc:

> public String readLine()
>                  throws IOException
>
> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed
>   ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.
>
> Returns:
>
> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination
>   characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()